# Is there a way stop table from sorting in R

Tags: r, sorting, csv

**Problem setup**: Creating a function to take multiple CSV files selected by ID column and combine into 1 csv, then create an output of number of observations by ID.

*Expected*:

```
complete("specdata", 30:25) ##notice descending order of IDs requested

##   id nobs
## 1 30  932
## 2 29  711
## 3 28  475
## 4 27  338
## 5 26  586
## 6 25  463
```

*I get:*

```
> complete("specdata", 30:25)

  id nobs
1 25  463
2 26  586
3 27  338
4 28  475
5 29  711
6 30  932
```

Which is "wrong" because it has been sorted by id.

The CSV file I read from does have the data in descending order. My snippet:

```
dfTable<-read.csv("~/progAssign1/specdata/tmpdata.csv")
ccTab<-complete.cases(dfTable)
xTab3<-as.data.frame(table(dfTable$ID[ccTab]),)
colnames(xTab3)<-c("id","nobs")
```

And as near as I can tell, the third line is where sorting occurs. I broke out the expression and it happens in the table() call. I've not found any option or parameter I can pass to make something like sort=FALSE. You'd think...

Anyway. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would just reorder the output from `table`, see `order` for that. And if you want to get into the R-way-of-doing-things I'd have a look at the `dplyr` package and any other Hadley Wickham package for that matter.

Comment: To answer your question: there is no hidden switch in `table` (it relies on `tabulate` which relies itself on a C function) => So you have to do the re-ordering yourself.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I would take some issue with claiming that dplyr is a good way to see the "R-way" of doing things. It is not really typical of R programing to use infix operators and passing results from left to right. I agree that once you have learned to think "functionally" (by enclosing arguments in functions) that dplyr is very slick and a real gift to the R-world, but it seems to me to be R from a somewhat atypical (but admittedly elegant) viewpoint.

Comment: I'm not understanding your repeated complaint about expecting the order of input for a tabulation operation to be affected by the order of input. That would not seem to be the mark of a "modern" computer language, whatever that is. R is not SAS, and it's not C, and it's not C++. It is a statistical workbench. The only way to progress is to pay attention to underlying structures and learn to use `list`, `tapply`, `ave`, "[", "[[", `order`, `match`, and `merge`. Then you can decide whether you want to go with data.table or dplyr or reshape2, since each one is essentially a fork of basic R.

Comment: @BondedDust: I'm not complaining. I'm observing.

Comment: Maybe it's a statistics thing, but it seems to me that a contingency table doesn't require any specific ordering because it's context may be different in different situations. So if my data were "Age" and "# of wrinkles in face", then I might want to see it from youngest to oldest or oldest to youngest without having to code an `if` and using `rev()` to accommodate the case where a user wants to see the data one way or another. Since I set up the data to be according to that preference in earlier steps, it's annoying to have it changed subsequently. But, as I stated: it is what it is.

Comment: The solution here does not really solve the problem. You can read the files into a data frame in the order you want, but how did you condense the data afterwards without using table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get around this is...don't use `table`.  Here's an example where I create three one-line data sets from your data. Then I read them in with a descending sequence, with `read.table` and it seems to be okay.

**The real big thing here is that multiple data sets should be placed in a list upon being read into R. You'll get the exact order of data sets you want that way, among other benefits.**

Once you've read them into R the way you want them, it's much easier to order them at the very end.  Ordering of rows (for me) is usually the very last step.

```
> dat <- read.table(h=T, text = "id nobs
  1 25  463
  2 26  586
  3 27  338
  4 28  475
  5 29  711
  6 30  932")
```

Write three one-line files:

```
> write.table(dat[3,], "dat3.csv", row.names = FALSE)
> write.table(dat[2,], "dat2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
> write.table(dat[1,], "dat1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Read them in using a `3:1` order:

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(3:1, function(x){ 
       read.table(paste0("dat", x, ".csv"), header = TRUE) 
  }))
#   id nobs
# 1 27  338
# 2 26  586
# 3 25  463
```

Then, if we change `3:1` to `1:3` the rows "comply" with our request

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(1:3, function(x){
      read.table(paste0("dat", x, ".csv"), header = TRUE)
  }))
#   id nobs
# 1 25  463
# 2 26  586
# 3 27  338
```

And just for `fun`

```
> fun <- function(z){
      do.call(rbind, lapply(z, function(x){ 
          read.table(paste0("dat", x, ".csv"), header = TRUE) }))
  }
> fun(c(2, 3, 1))
#   id nobs
# 1 26  586
# 2 27  338
# 3 25  463
```

Comment: I started with rbind and something else. Problem is I'm on week 2 of class and NONE of this was covered: sooooo frustrating! I was trying to stay away from the deeper things, but I think I'll "borrow" this without fully understanding it at the moment, just because it's due tomorrow. Then I will write me up a function for this because it simply makes more sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem is in the output of `table`, which are sorted by default. For example:

```
> r = sample(5,15,replace = T)
> r
 [1] 1 4 1 1 3 5 3 2 1 4 2 4 2 4 4
> table(r)
r
1 2 3 4 5 
4 3 2 5 1
```

If you want to take the order of first appearance, you are going to get your hands a little bit dirty by recoding the `table` function:

```
unique_r = unique(r)
table_r = rbind(label=unique_r, count=sapply(unique_r,function(x)sum(r==x)))
table_r
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
label    1    4    3    5    2
count    4    5    2    1    3
```

Comment: Yeah... and so my comment about doing things in one line of code and sometimes having to code more. My complaint with R is "by default" -- if it were a default, which I could override, I'd be happier :). But thanks for the info and the response! I've vote up but I have a lousy reputation atm...

Comment: I believe the "problem" lies in `factor` called by `table`: `table(factor(r, levels = c(1, 4, 3, 5, 2)))`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
t1 <- c(5,3,1,3,5,5,5)
as.data.frame(table(t1)) ##result in ascending order
 # t1 Freq
#1  1    1
#2  3    2
#3  5    4

 t1 <- factor(t1)
 as.data.frame(table(reorder(t1, rep(-1, length(t1)),sum)))
# Var1 Freq
#1    5    4
#2    3    2
#3    1    1
```

Comment: Good stuff to know, but in this case, I would have to detect that the request was in descending order and then code an "if" to either use this or to let it go because the request was in ascending order...

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are complaining about the actions of the `table` function with a single argument returning the items with the names in ascending order and you wnat them in descending order. You could have simply used the rev() function around the `table` call.

```
xTab3<-as.data.frame( rev( table( dfTable$ID[ccTab] ) ),)
```

(I'm not sure what that last comma is doing in there.) The sort order in the original would not be expected to determine the order of a table operation. Generally R will return results with discrete labels sorted in alpha (ascending) order unless the levels of a factor item have been specified differently. That's one of those R-specific rules that may be difficult to intuit. The other R-specific rule that may be difficult to grasp (although not really a problem here) is that arguments are often expected to be in the form of R-lists.

It's probably wise to think about R-table objects at this point (and what happens with the `as.data.frame` call. `table`-objects are actually R-matrices, so the feature that you wanted to sort by was actually the rownames of that table object and are of class character:

```
r = sample(5,15,replace = T)
table(r)
#r
#2 3 4 5 
#5 3 2 5 
rownames(table(r))
#[1] "2" "3" "4" "5"

str(as.data.frame(table(r)))
#-------
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ r   : Factor w/ 4 levels "2","3","4","5": 1 2 3 4
 $ Freq: int  5 3 2 5
```

Comment: I think the comma was left over from a previous attempt... R seems to make simple things more difficult at the expense of making difficult things simpler. I appreciate your response, though.

Comment: And rev() is good to know, but, again, in this context, I would need to code a flow control, to determine whether or not I needed to reverse the table.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanna share this homework I've done

```
complete <- function(directory, id=1:332){
    setwd("E:/Coursera")
    files <- dir(directory, full.names = TRUE)
    data <- lapply(files, read.csv)
    specdata <- do.call(rbind, data)

    cleandata <- specdata[!is.na(specdata$sulfate) & !is.na(specdata$nitrate),]
    targetdata <- data.frame(Date=numeric(0), sulfate=numeric(0), nitrate=numeric(0), ID=numeric(0))
    result<-data.frame(id=numeric(0), nobs=numeric(0))

    for(i in id){
        targetdata <- cleandata[cleandata$ID == i, ]
        result <- rbind(result, data.frame(table(targetdata$ID)))
    }

    names(result) <- c("id","nobs")
    result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that no one has proposed yet is combining `table()` with `unique()` function. The `unique()` function does the behaviour that you are looking (listing unique IDs in order of appearance).
In your case it would be something like this:

```
dfTable<-read.csv("~/progAssign1/specdata/tmpdata.csv")
ccTab<-complete.cases(dfTable)
x<-dfTable$ID[ccTab] #unique IDs
xTab3<-as.data.frame(table(x)[unique(x)],) #here you sort the "table()" result in order of appearance
colnames(xTab3)<-c("id","nobs")
```