# Is there a way to stop read.csv from sorting my lines?

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the data they I selected them, but it seems read.csv sorting them out or may be dplyr, but I want plot the selected names they way I put them. Is there a way to do that?

These are my data and code:

```
dfc <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv"))

dfg <- dfc %>% dplyr::filter(tracking_id %in% c('S100a10', 'Esm1', 'Itgb1', 'Anxa2', 'Hist1h1b', 
                                                'Il2rb', 'Lgals1', 'Mki67', 'Rora', 'S100a4', 
                                                'S100a6', 'Adam8', 'Areg', 'Bcl2l1', 'Calca', 
                                                'Capg', 'Ccr2', 'Cd44', 'Csda', 'Ehd1', 
                                                'Id2', 'Il10', 'Il1rl1', 'Il2ra', 'Lmna', 
                                                'Maf', 'Penk', 'Podnl1', 'Tiam1', 'Vim',
                                                'Ern1', 'Furin', 'Ifng', 'Igfbp7', 'Il13', 
                                                'Il4', 'Il5', 'Nrp1', 'Ptprs', 'Rbpj', 
                                                'Spry1', 'Tnfsf11', 'Vdr', 'Xcl1', 'Bmpr2', 
                                                'Csf1', 'Dst', 'Foxp3', 'Itgav', 'Itgb8', 
                                                'Lamc1', 'Myo1e', 'Pmaip1', 'Prdm1', 'Ptpn5', 
                                                'Ramp1', 'Sdc4')) 
head(dfg)
```

I was hoping to find a solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842157/is-there-a-way-stop-table-from-sorting-in-r), but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%in%` will subset the data based on how it is present in your dataframe and not based on the vector that you filter. If you want the same order you can use `match` :

```
library(dplyr)
dfc %>% slice(match(values, tracking_id))
```

which in base R can be written as :

```
dfc[match(values, dfc$tracking_id), ]
```

where `values` is :

```
values <- c('S100a10', 'Esm1', 'Itgb1', 'Anxa2', 'Hist1h1b', 
            'Il2rb', 'Lgals1', 'Mki67', 'Rora', 'S100a4', 
            'S100a6', 'Adam8', 'Areg', 'Bcl2l1', 'Calca', 
            'Capg', 'Ccr2', 'Cd44', 'Csda', 'Ehd1', 
            'Id2', 'Il10', 'Il1rl1', 'Il2ra', 'Lmna', 
            'Maf', 'Penk', 'Podnl1', 'Tiam1', 'Vim',
            'Ern1', 'Furin', 'Ifng', 'Igfbp7', 'Il13', 
            'Il4', 'Il5', 'Nrp1', 'Ptprs', 'Rbpj', 
            'Spry1', 'Tnfsf11', 'Vdr', 'Xcl1', 'Bmpr2', 
            'Csf1', 'Dst', 'Foxp3', 'Itgav', 'Itgb8', 
            'Lamc1', 'Myo1e', 'Pmaip1', 'Prdm1', 'Ptpn5', 
            'Ramp1', 'Sdc4')
```

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah ! it worked, how can I reverse the order of the same values using `dfc[match(values, dfc$tracking_id), ]` ?

Comment: Reverse the values. `dfc[match(rev(values), dfc$tracking_id), ]`

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to convert your variable to a factor with the levels in the desired order. Afterwards you can arrange your data accordingly:

```r
library(dplyr)

dfc <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/learnseq/learning/raw/main/GSE133399_Fig2_FPKM.csv"))

ids <- c('S100a10', 'Esm1', 'Itgb1', 'Anxa2', 'Hist1h1b', 
         'Il2rb', 'Lgals1', 'Mki67', 'Rora', 'S100a4', 
         'S100a6', 'Adam8', 'Areg', 'Bcl2l1', 'Calca', 
         'Capg', 'Ccr2', 'Cd44', 'Csda', 'Ehd1', 
         'Id2', 'Il10', 'Il1rl1', 'Il2ra', 'Lmna', 
         'Maf', 'Penk', 'Podnl1', 'Tiam1', 'Vim',
         'Ern1', 'Furin', 'Ifng', 'Igfbp7', 'Il13', 
         'Il4', 'Il5', 'Nrp1', 'Ptprs', 'Rbpj', 
         'Spry1', 'Tnfsf11', 'Vdr', 'Xcl1', 'Bmpr2', 
         'Csf1', 'Dst', 'Foxp3', 'Itgav', 'Itgb8', 
         'Lamc1', 'Myo1e', 'Pmaip1', 'Prdm1', 'Ptpn5', 
         'Ramp1', 'Sdc4')

dfg <- dfc %>% 
  filter(tracking_id %in% ids) %>% 
  mutate(tracking_id = factor(tracking_id, levels = ids)) %>% 
  arrange(tracking_id)
head(dfg)
#>   tracking_id CD44low_rep1 CD44hi_CD69low_rep1 CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep1
#> 1     S100a10    24.185300            215.9770                   191.19900
#> 2        Esm1     0.292527             11.6737                     1.31048
#> 3       Itgb1     2.783530             75.2682                    76.31740
#> 4       Anxa2     0.771864             20.1817                    23.60150
#> 5    Hist1h1b     1.784150             47.6620                    24.46870
#> 6       Il2rb     1.309430             25.4487                    57.04810
#>   CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep1 CD44low_rep2 CD44hi_CD69low_rep2
#> 1                 221.072000   25.8888000            216.7610
#> 2                   0.989497    0.0556449             11.3918
#> 3                  11.118500    2.8061500             61.1956
#> 4                  13.964600    0.4517920             20.5154
#> 5                  64.651200    0.6789370             51.1621
#> 6                  60.663400    1.1446900             23.3560
#>   CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103low_rep2 CD44hi_CD69hi_CD103hi_rep2
#> 1                   201.88600                  213.88400
#> 2                     2.08267                    1.25273
#> 3                    57.41610                    9.42745
#> 4                    21.44850                   11.18830
#> 5                    40.79160                   43.77030
#> 6                    65.39240                   50.75980
```

Comment: Thank you @stefan ! but I'm not sure if I want to convert them to factor, because l'm not sure if it will affect down the stream processing

Comment: You can convert it back to a character after arranging, i.e. add `mutate(tracking_id = as.character(tracking_id))`. However, overall the answer by @RonakShah is definitely the simpler solution to get your desired result.

Comment: And your is great too @stefan ,I appreciate your support, I will try it afterward. I'm just slow at debugging, I have to go check line by line when there is something wrong, which is time consuming, but it is always good to learn something new. Can you take  a look at this question that I need help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826379/how-to-add-dots-to-x-axis-of-the-plot?noredirect=1#comment114619315_64826379